# Rooting VS permissions

Tags: android, permissions, root

first of all, I'm not involved in **any** kind of Android development. I'm only curious.

The question is: does an app obtaining root privileges still need to declare its required permissions in the manifest?

I mean, if my app doesn't declare that it needs to acquire camera input, can it invoke some APIs or executable and acquire camera *after* becoming root?

I know this could sound stupid but I repeat, I'm just curious about Android features.

Comment: Of course, good sense and expertise in Linux *tells* me that it is possible, since when you are SU you can do anything you want over the system. I don't know if I'm correct in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your typical rooted Android device, (which would use the [Superuser](http://androidsu.com/superuser/) application and its corresponding `su` binary) applications which request root access can only run commands as root via the `su` binary.

So **yes**, in that the application itself still runs as a underprivileged user process, so anything it needs to do using the "normal" APIs still need the correct permissions. So if you want to (as in your example) access the camera using the normal Java API, you can't do that unless you have declared that permission.

But **no**, in that if your application [requests and receives root privileges](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/) via the `su` binary, you can do anything you want within that command. So if you wrote a special binary or script that can access the camera outside of the normal API methods, that might work. (I suspect this would be more trouble than it's worth.)

Comment: Second part of the question is unclear. You said that the app can run rooted commands via su with full privileges, but invokes APIs as unprivileged. Then, as soon as no *su*doable executable exists that performs the undeclared feature (ie. a command that acquires camera input and allows the running app to use its stream, or just any other thing) then the app cannot run what's not declared. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, (I edited the answer probably at the same time as you wrote that) the root access is limited to the process spawned by your `su`. Your application retains its existing permissions in the Java world. You would have to come up with a way to access the camera outside of the normal Java API, unless you figure out a way to launch another Java application as root.

Comment: Another interesting comment. So, it's not that straightforward to launch a Java application as root, is it? I really don't know much about android development, but I'm very interested into it

Comment: Correct; I don't believe it's straightforward. You might manage to run a Java application but I'm not sure if you could get it to display a UI, since at that point you're outside of the UI framework provided by the Android OS, which was not designed to ever run end-user applications as root due to the obvious security risk. (there is actually a factory test mode for this, but it's not enabled for production devices)